# WIN Command Prompt: [TestNG] [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: <file Name>

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, command-prompt

I'm trying to run a TESTNG file from command prompt.
ALL test cases except for a specific Test Case is not running from command prompt. The same Testcase is NOT throwing any error from ECLIPSE. The suite is described below.  The Start_suite alone is not running. The other testcase is working if the start_suite is commented. What can be the mistake I'm doing

```
    <suite name="Sample Tests" verbose="1">
      <listeners>
      <listener class-name="com.frmwrk.listener.CustomTestListener" />
      <listener class-name="com.frmwrk.listener.CustomizedReporter" />
      </listeners>
      <test name="TestRun" preserve-order="true">
     <groups>
     <run>
          < exclude name="reboot" />
     </run>
     </groups>
     <classes>
     <class name="com.test.Start_Suite" />
     </classes>
     </test>    
        <test name="Reboot TEST" preserve-order="true" parallel="false">
        <groups>
            <run>
               <exclude name="Setup" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>

        <class name= "com.test.1_Reboot" />

       </classes>
       </test>
      </suite>
```

Comment: i think you have a Typo over there there's a space between <' 'exclude which is why xml is not getting parsed

Comment: Hi, did you tried without space as suggested. <run>
          <exclude name="reboot" />
     </run>

Comment: this is an edited version.. There is no space in the original code. Can there be any other reason? Will there be an error if a test class extends another class